# How to create an Activity or Sequence Diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have downloaded a latest version of Enterprise Architect and I want to create an activity and a sequence diagrams. But I can't find those 2 in creation wizard.

Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new project after providing its location in your disk , a model wizard would be showed choose Basic UML 2 technology from the Technology menu and check domain model in the right side, after in the project browser click on the new diagram icon as mentioned in the following screenshot :

[image]

after clicking on that icon the wizard in the following screenshot will be fired, try to follow the steps:

[image]